How to make a forest plot table with subheadings?
I would like to know how to code a forest plot table to include subheadings, such as the ones shown below (not my graph, but I would like to make one like this). The subheadings don't have values associated with them. I also want the forest plot to be displayed with different colors for groups for each variable.
I have tried to play around with codes in this post but am not getting what I wanted.
Forest plot with table ggplot coding
My current dataframe is as follows:
df <- data.frame(
  Variables = c("Overall", "Female", "Male", "0-16", "17-40","40+","Overall", "Female", "Male", "0-16", "17-40","40+"),
  Observed = c(184, 211, 152, 66, 149, 458, 169, 163, 178, 13, 39, 438),
  Expected = c(50, 45, 57, 9, 33, 170, 102, 94, 112, 5, 21, 267),
  SMR = c(3.66, 4.71, 2.68, 7.66, 4.51, 2.7, 1.66, 1.74, 1.58, 2.61, 1.81, 1.64),
  SMRlo = c(2.79, 3.32, 1.69, 1.68, 3.12, 1.7, 1.61, 1.66, 1.51, 1.76, 1.66, 1.58),
  SMRhi = c(4.72, 6.48, 4.02, 21.59, 6.29, 4.06, 1.72, 1.81, 1.66, 3.71, 1.98, 1.7),
  Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  Subheading = c(NA, "Sex", "Sex", "Age at CD Onset (years)", "Age at CD Onset (years)", "Age at CD Onset (years)", NA, "Sex", "Sex", "Age at CD Onset (years)", "Age at CD Onset (years)", "Age at CD Onset (years)")
)


